# VS Code intellisense not working for data in vue sfc component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have simple code like this

[image]

but inside the method, 'name' is considered as any. If I hover the name in data it shows it as string.

vetur plugin is isntalled already.

```
// tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "types": [
      "vite/client"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Vetur has been deprecated for Volar. Switching should resolve the issue.

Comment: tried Volar, it still showing name as any

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Changing `noImplicitThis` to `true` will give you the intellisense.